# log4j not finding .properties file despite being in WEB-INF/classes

Tags: hibernate, log4j, classloader

I have a highly annoying issue wherein log4j refuses to find the properties file in my new project.  I am using Hibernate4, which uses jboss-logging for some ungodly reason.  I have a log4j.properties in my WEB-INF/classes by making a resources source folder.  I can see the log4j.properties in the classes folder so i know RAD is picking up the file as source.  It looks like as follows:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout
log4j.gov.usdoj=INFO

#Direct log messages to the console
log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{2}[%M:%L] %p %m%n

# Hibernate logging options(INFO only shows startup messages)
#org.hibernate Log everything. This is a lot of information but it is useful for troubleshooting 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=WARN
#org.hibernate.type Log all JDBC parameters 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=WARN
#org.hibernate.SQL Log all SQL DML statements as they are executed (like show_sql setting) 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.sql=WARN
#org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl Log all SQL DDL statements as they are executed 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=WARN
#org.hibernate.pretty Log the state of all entities (max 20 entities) associated with the session at flush time 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.pretty=WARN
#org.hibernate.cache Log all second-level cache activity 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=WARN
#org.hibernate.transaction Log transaction related activity 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=WARN
#org.hibernate.jdbc Log all JDBC resource acquisition 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=WARN
#org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.AST Log HQL and SQL ASTs during query parsing 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.AST=WARN
#org.hibernate.secure Log all JAAS authorization requests 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.secure=WARN
```

But I have put deliberate errors (like XML) in it and it doesn't "blow up" so I am pretty sure that log4j isn't even finding it.  I get  a "no appenders" error on startup pointing to (org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry).  I have hibernate-jpa in a bootstrap area because RAD has a different version of the same jar it runs and we vet the Orphan ManyToOne error if we don't put hibernate-jpa in the bootstrap area.  If someone knows a better solution to that, I'd like to hear it because I hate doing that.

But the topic at hand is that for some reason on this project I can't get log4j to find that log4j.properties file.  I kind of suspect i am the victim of the classloader issue with the hibernate thing, but log4j.jar is in my WEB-INF/lib.